# How to build a linked list with a method that has two integer parameters and returns the reference to the first element of a list of nodes?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

So I am having trouble trying to build a linked list from a method that has two integer parameters n and m. Parameter n is the length of nodes of the linked list, and m is the parameter that contains random integers from 0 to m-1 inside the list of nodes. I am required to build this linked list from a predefined Node class that cannot be changed, and to return the reference to the first element from the linked list. I don't know how to traverse the linked list in the while loop.

Node class

```
public class iNode{
public int item;
public iNode next;

public iNode(int i, iNode n){ 
    item = i; 
    next = n; 
}
public iNode(int i){ 
    item = i; 
    next = null; 
}
```

Build the linked list method

```
    public static iNode list(int n, int m){

    iNode first; 
    iNode newNode;
    iNode last;


    first = null;
    while ( )
    {
        newNode = new iNode(m, first.next);
        if (m > 0){
            newNode.item = m-1;
        }
        newNode.next = null; 

        if (first == null)
        {
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }

    }
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it. Just go from the end of the list and add nodes with the link to the previous one. In the end just return the last created node. Also, you are not adding random int from the range 0..m-1. Here it is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        iNode res = list(5, 10);

        while(res != null){
            System.out.println(res.item);
            res = res.next;
        }
    }

    public static iNode list(int n, int m) {

        iNode previous;
        iNode current;

        int i = 0;
        previous = null;
        while (i < n) {
            current = new iNode(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, m), previous);
            previous = current;

            i++;
        }
        return previous;
    }
```

Output:

```
2
5
7
8
9
```

P.S. Please follow java code convention. Class names should start with capital letter - `iNode`

Comment: Yes, but how can i generate random numbers from m-1 to 0 range.